# python & android and googlemaps

Tags: python, android, google-maps

I'm making a game depending on android and python (client and server ) and i neeed the client to choose a place too play in it from google maps and send the x & y cordinnates to the python then python add points to the areaa the client will play in .. soo how can i do this in python and thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is probably to have the python server side of things send the coordinates back to the Android app in its response and then the android app can manipulate the map as needed.

Comment: can u please tell me how to install pygmaps (all its classes) using python and already have Activepython and try {pypm install pygamps ) but this way faileed !! anyother susgestion

Comment: Unfortunately I can't be any help with the second bit.  I've never worked with pygmaps at all and do what little python work I do on Linux, so I've also never touched ActivePython.